# Log all function invocations to console

Tags: c#, logging, trace

It occurs pretty often that I start debugging a class by logging every function call to console and looking for differences in the bugged cases.
Is there some attribute that I can apply to a class to enable such a tracing? It's pretty exhausting to have to enter these

```
Console.WriteLine("classname: methodname")
```

to every method and to remove them afterwards (removing can be done by conditional compilation, but it is not very nice to look at the code when you have all this redundance)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an add-on tool someone mentioned to me, using Attributes. Let's see if I can find it.

I think it was PostSharp:

[Article](http://blogs.conchango.com/merrickchaffer/archive/2009/08/04/using-postsharp-to-log-method-entry-and-exit-in-net-code.aspx)

http://www.postsharp.org/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/) to intercept all method calls and print them even with all arguments and it does not require source code changes. This [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ps-custom-attributes-1.aspx) shows how to do logging with PostSharp.

Just to note, PostSharp is an [aspect-oriented programming (AOP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) framework and there are some more.

Answer (score 1):

If log4net is as good as log4j, then you are all set

http://logging.apache.org/log4net//index.html

Answer (score 0):

In the dim dark ages of software engineering, one often used a profiling tool to achieve that since profiling injected extra code at entry and exit of all functions, although I must say that this is a pretty dismal approach to debugging and when I used it, it was a desperation move not front line.  Debugging by print statement is fairly slow and ineffective.

Comment: It gives you some information about the flow of the program. Effectiveness depends on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

AOP is supported also by http://www.springframework.net/